# Distribute post content through several divs

Tags: plugins, posts, content, design

I would like to distribute the content in a post through several divs. Much like a word processor distributes content through pages.
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question. Will they be random div's. Will the div's take the place of <p> tags? Are you using divs so you can add a class or ID, or just for a spacer?

Comment: Are you talking about something like `<!--nextpage-->`?

Comment: Using <!--nextpage--> is half way the idea. <!--nextpage--> causes the content to continue in another div. But I want it to work automatically. Like you decide the divs are not to be  longer than 300 px. If the content fills the first div it will continue in the next one.

Comment: Using a columns plugin to distribute content in columns is a good parable. Only I dont want it visually like columns. I want to be able to position them anywhere on the page. Does this make my intentions clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You can either use a jQuery plugin like [columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) (even if you don't do columns, you can repurpose this plugin to split it how you want), or you can do it with PHP. Here's [a great article](http://www.sitepoint.com/split-wordpress-content-into-multiple-sections/) that should get your started.